# JQUERY Dialog handle postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JQuery dialog in asp.net

Once I clicked the button, the dialog pop up then disappears immediately. I know there is a post-back issue, butI don't know how to handle it? Say using hidden field?

[image: code for the dialog]

Comment: sorry, i was trying to insert code, but seems that I always get alert on format, which prevent me from posting, and I feels that's inconvenient~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is `asp.net server` control i.e its `submit` button which causes `form` submission and eventually `postback`.

Change it to normal `html button`

```
<input type="button" value="open dialog" id="btn"/>
```

then open popup on click of that button

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
//open dialog
});
```

Or if you dont want to replace server control with html control, you can `return false` from `click` function

CODE

```
  ......
 {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: @user3344443 all controls are eventually parsed to normal html, but if u inspect elemtn in browser u will see that asp button is <input type="submit"

Comment: Yes of course its ok as u dont want to submit your page on that button click

Comment: the return false looks great. though I actually have some buttons inside my dialog box (i haven't posted yet), what should I do after I click a button inside the dialog box? is it return true?

Comment: depends on what code u have written on dialog button click

Comment: now my dialog is $('#<%=updateBI.clientID%>').click(function confirm () {

                $('div#thedialog').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    buttons: {
                        "Yes": function () {  alert('you chose yes'); },
                        "No": function () { alert('you chose no'); },
                        "Cancel": function () { alert('you chose cancel'); }
                    }
                });

                $('div#thedialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        })

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49062/discussion-between-nitin-varpe-and-user3344443)

Comment: how do I do that? I'm actually new to stackoverflow

Comment: cant get it. if your button is server control, u always need to return false to stop form submission

Comment: you cant join chat coz of ur reputation its ok

Comment: i posted my buttons in above comments. suppose after I click yes, the dialog would disappear. How could I achieve that?

Comment: use $('#dialog').dialog('close')

Comment: I see..I also have <div id="thedialog" title="Download complete">
     <p>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
        Your files have downloaded successfull...           for the dialog box. problem is that when I run in the browser, the message already displays there before I click the button. IS there a way to handle itÉ

Comment: please on which event its shown and show it on button click only

Comment: I tried something like visible=`false`in .net but it dones`t seem to help.. sorry I`m new to jquery

Comment: cant get ur issue and requirement

Comment: say I have <p> download complete <p/> I put this one inside my dialog box. And I only want it to show after i click a button. Should I use vb or js to show it on button click only?

Comment: use js only $('p').css('display','block'); initially keep display to none

Comment: I see, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry, after I have return false, each time when I update the data, the website doesn't postback. I only need return false during the period the dialog box stays. After I click a button inside the dialog box, I want the website to postback. What should I do?

Comment: then you can remove return false on click of dialog button